# Spring Feign configuration: how to test all @Bean methods are called

Tags: java, spring, mocking, spring-cloud-feign

I want to configure Spring feign with a configuration class, and I want to make sure that all the `@Bean` methods are called when Spring configures the feign client for me.

How to test it?

For example, I have:

```
@FeignClient(
        name = "PreAuthSendRequest",
        url = "${xxx.services.preauth.send.url}",
        configuration = AppFeignConfig.class)
public interface RequestService {
    @PostMapping("")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    PreAuthResponse execute(@RequestBody PreAuthRequest preAuthRequest);
}
```

And `AppFeignConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppFeignConfig{

    private final HttpClient httpClient;
    private final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder contextObjectMapperBuilder;

    @Bean
    public ApacheHttpClient client() {
        return new ApacheHttpClient(httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        return new JacksonDecoder((ObjectMapper)contextObjectMapperBuilder.build());
    }

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new JacksonEncoder((ObjectMapper)contextObjectMapperBuilder.build());
    }

    @Bean
    public Retryer retryer() {
        return Retryer.NEVER_RETRY;
    }


    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return new ServiceResponseErrorDecoder();
    }
}
```

So, how to verify that all `@Bean` methods are called? I know `@MockBean`, but what I want to check is `config.feignDecoder()`, etc., are indeed called.

When I am trying to `context.getBean(RequestService.class);` and call `execute()` method, it seems to send a real request and without wiremock, it fails, obviously.

Comment: That seems a lot like testing the specific implementation and the framework. What's the *behaviour* you want to test?

Comment: So you mean, this is implementation related and not to do with behaviour? Or, this part, getting the correct bean, is not meant to test?

Comment: I feel that putting a log message (with DEBUG level) inside each of those methods would be a good way to ensure that they are called (instead of testing them)

Comment: Yes @ali4j this could also be a good solution. I am considering this but I don't know; the overhead of redirecting the stdout to a file and check that has been done some times in this project. Maybe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I must say that I agree with you to some extent, I kind of think that it should be part of integration tests but I am not sure, still confused about behaviour tests and unit tests...

Answer (score -2):

For now I have this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class RequestServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private ApacheHttpClient client;

    @MockBean
    private Decoder feignDecoder;

    @MockBean
    private Encoder feignEncoder;

    @MockBean
    private Retryer retryer;

    @MockBean
    private ErrorDecoder errorDecoder;

    @Test
    void shouldRetrieveBeansFromApplicationContextToConstructConfigurationInstance() {
        AppFeignConfig config = applicationContext.getBean(AppFeignConfig.class);
        Assertions.assertEquals(config.feignEncoder(), feignEncoder);
        Assertions.assertEquals(config.feignDecoder(), feignDecoder);
        Assertions.assertEquals(config.errorDecoder(), errorDecoder);
        Assertions.assertEquals(config.client(), client);
        Assertions.assertEquals(config.retryer(), retryer);
    }

}
```

I don't know if it is how it should be. If any idea, please comment.

Comment: Please comment with reasoning, if you think this is not what should be done, especially when you downvote.